# MongoDB search for multiple filter-criteria in one query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, filter, wildcard

I have a collection i want to search in, and user has the possibility to search vor various combinations.

In detail user can set filter for following:

dateFrom,
dateTo,
owner,
shop,
event

Frontend sends an array of objects "filterData" to the backend in the request.

If no filter is set, the object value is an empty string that should equal to "all".

Now i want to get one search string, for all possible conditions.

Example 1: Find all data with "owner1"

dateFrom: "",
dateTo: "",
owner: owner1,
shop: "",
event: ""

Example 2: Find all data, that has "owner2" and "event1"
dateFrom: "",
dateTo: "",
owner: "owner2,
shop: "",
event: event1

```
      const data = await Dataset.find({
        $and: [
          {
            date: {
              $gte: Date.parse(filterData.dateFrom),
              $lte: Date.parse(filterData.dateTo),
            },
          },
          { shop: filterData.selectedShops },
          { event: filterData.selectedEvents },
          { owner: filterData.owner },
        ],
      });
```

right now everything works as i expect, but i have to set all filters. Now i have to find a solution to tell mongodb to send me "all" if one of the requested values equals an empty string.

Maybe ternary like {shop: filterData.selectedShops.length <1 ? "here i need a wildcard or something that queries for "all" : filterData.selectedShops}

I hope the description is ok and you can understand my problem.

Comment: First of all, you don't need the `$and`, by default you can search by multiple fields. Second, the query is an object, you can remove or add fields in your code according to the input from the FE, before executing the query

Comment: Thanks for your reply - so i should remove the AND and manipulate the request if it is an empty string and replace the empty string with a wildcard for example like this {owner: "owner1", event: /.*./}

???

Comment: You don't need an empty string, you can simply remove the key from the filter object